# How can I lookup the data transmission times between nodes in a cluster?

Tags: cassandra

I am new to Cassandra and learning it, how can I look times data transmission between nodes of cassandra cluster or which set up parameters I can look the times transmission between nodes ?

thxs in advance

Answer (score 2):

As long as you are using Cassandra 3.8 or higher, you can monitor CrossNodeLatency mbean, added by this improvement:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11569

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, Cassandra collects several latency metrics. Latency is a special type of metric that tracks latency with a timer and a counter (see [Monitoring metric types](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/metrics.html) for details).

When a node sends data to another node, the time that the request was sent by a node is included in the message header so the receiving node is able to measure how long it took to send the message.

#### JMX

The cross-node latency metric records a histogram of the amount of time it took for messages to go from sender nodes to a receiving node. The mbean coordinates for this metric is:

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name=CrossNodeLatency
```

The cross-DC latency metric records a histogram of the amount of time it took for messages to reach a node in the destination DC. The mbean coordinates for this metric is:

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Messaging,name=<DC_name>-Latency
```

You can query these metrics through JMX using tools such as `jconsole` or `jmxterm`.

#### Node tool

Alternatively, there are `nodetool` commands which report some relevant network statistics.

[The `nodetool proxyhistograms` command](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/nodetool/proxyhistograms.html) prints out a histogram of read and write latencies between nodes as recorded by request coordinators.

[The `nodetool tablehistograms` command](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/tools/nodetool/tablehistograms.html) prints out statistics for a specific table that includes read and write latencies among other metrics.

Finally, it is worth noting that a significant proportion of the time spent sending and receiving messages is network latency. We recommend that you monitor the network between servers and across DCs, particularly if latency is a major concern for you. Cheers!